# How to receive complete data in python?

Tags: python, video, web, stream, recv

I am trying to stream a video from one laptop to another connected in the same network. As there is no `recvall` in python, i have tried this loop but i am not able to break out of this loop. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

```
data = ""    
while 1:
    strng = s.recv(size_data)
    data += strng
    if not strng: break
datatodecode=np.fromstring(data,dtype='uint8')
```

In the server side:

```
while 1:  
    conn.send(size_of_size)                 
    conn.send(size_data)                   
    conn.sendall(strng)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This code won't even run as `strng` is not defined. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the code. please check

Comment: This code *will* receive the entire video and block until it's done that. But if you want to **stream** a video, then you **don't** want to block until the entire video has been received. So which is it, do you want to stream it or transfer it completely?

Comment: I want to stream the video.If i could break this loop after receiving the complete data, then i could carry out other process, but this loop runs continuosly

Comment: This code _will_ break after receiving the _complete_ data. But a webcam will keep capturing video material until it's turned off, so _this code will keep receiving data until you turn off your webcam_. So the question is, **what do you want to do with the video?**  If you just want to save the video, then your code is fine. But if you want to display it in real time, then you have to change your code. (I'm assuming you're streaming a webcam video because of your other question.)

Comment: I have added the server side code above.In the server side i am continuously sending data so the loop won't break. So how could i break from this loop after receiving the third parameter (strng)

Comment: Read out the `size_data` from the data you've received and then `if len(data)>=size_data: break`?

Comment: Rawing Thanx man.You are a lifesaver.why didn't i think of that?